# 400 Bad request when creating app in Intune using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

Im trying to create an app in Intune using the MS Graph.

When post to the following endpoint and using the json body below I get a `400 bad request` response

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps
```

Is the json body wrong? The formatting is correct and all the fields seem to be there

```
{
"id":  "553834731",
"bundleId":  "com.midasplayer.apps.candycrushsaga",
"notes":  "We hope you’re having fun playing Candy Crush Saga! We update the game every week so don\u0027t forget to download the latest version to get all the sweet new features and levels!\n\nNew to the game? Don’t be shy, join the fun! \n\nComing back after a break? About time! \n\nLet’s play!",
"createdDateTime":  "\/Date(1489497631738)\/",
"owner":  "",
"largeIcon":  {
                  "@odata.type":  "microsoft.graph.mimeContent",
                  "type":  "image/jpeg",
                  "value":  "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"
              },
"minimumSupportedOperatingSystem":  {
                                        "@odata.type":  "microsoft.graph.iosMinimumOperatingSystem",
                                        "v8_0":  "true",
                                        "v9_0":  "true",
                                        "v10_0":  "true"
                                    },
"description":  "Candy Crush Saga, from the makers of Candy Crush Soda Saga \n\u0026 Farm Heroes Saga!\n\nJoin Tiffi and Mr. Toffee on their sweet adventure through the Candy Kingdom. Travel through magical lands, visiting wondrous places and meeting deliciously kooky characters! Switch and match your way through hundreds of fun levels in this delicious puzzle adventure. The sweetest game just keeps getting sweeter!\n\nTake on this deliciously sweet Saga alone or play with friends to see who can get the top score! \n\nCandy Crush Saga is completely free to play but some optional \nin-game items will require payment.\n\nYou can turn off the payment feature by disabling in-app purchases in your device’s settings.\n\nCandy Crush Saga features:\n● Tasty ways to play: Target Score, Timed Levels, Drop Down Mode and Order Mode\n● Collect sugar drops to progress along the Sugar Track for super sweet surprises!\n● Spin the Daily Booster Wheel for a delicious prize\n● Pass level 50 to unlock Dreamworld and escape reality with Odus the Owl\n● Unwrap delicious environments and meet the sweetest characters\n● Tasty Candies, wrapped and striped Special Candies, Color Bombs and various other magical boosters to help with challenging levels\n● Hundreds of the best levels in the Candy Kingdom with more added every 2 weeks for your entertainment\n● Leaderboards to watch your friends and competitors!\n● It\u0027s easy to sync the game between devices and unlock full game features when connected to the Internet\n\nVisit https://care.king.com/ if you need help!\n\nFollow us to get news and updates;\nfacebook.com/CandyCrushSaga\nTwitter @CandyCrushSaga\nhttps://www.youtube.com/user/CandyCrushOfficial\nhttp://candycrushsaga.com/\n\nHave fun playing Candy Crush Saga!\n\nMinimum iOS version recommended: 5.1.1",
"lastModifiedDateTime":  "\/Date(1489497631738)\/",
"privacyInformationUrl":  "",
"@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.iosStoreApp",
"applicableDeviceType":  {
                             "@odata.type":  "microsoft.graph.iosDeviceType",
                             "iPad":  "true",
                             "iPhoneAndIPod":  "true"
                         },
"informationUrl":  "",
"developer":  "King",
"displayName":  "Candy Crush Saga",
"uploadState":  1,
"appStoreUrl":  "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8\u0026uo=4",
"installSummary":  {
                       "@odata.type":  "microsoft.graph.mobileAppInstallSummary",
                       "installedDeviceCount":  0,
                       "failedDeviceCount":  0,
                       "notInstalledDeviceCount":  0,
                       "installedUserCount":  0,
                       "failedUserCount":  0,
                       "notInstalledUserCount":  0
                   },
"publisher":  "King.com Limited",
"isFeatured":  "false"
```

}

Comment: I am trying to see how to use this endpoint to upload the *.apk binaries for an LOB app, as part of this payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on the Microsoft Intune Team.

There are a few fields in your request that are read-only and should not be included in the POST: id, createdDateTime, lastModifiedDateTime, uploadState, installSummary.

Also, minimumSupportedOperatingSystem can only have one of the values set to true and the others should be false.

We will update our documentation to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, I can see that some of these are self-explanatory that they are not needed in the request, but according to the documentation it says that they are required. I also realise that this is still the beta API, but thank you for updating the documentation.

Comment: I am trying to see how to use this endpoint to upload the *.apk binaries for an LOB app, as part of this payload.