# Intune Android/iOS app deployment API

Tags: intune

I'm supporting a company to plan for an **App deployment automation** through **Intune** which means *.apk/*.ipa can be **uploaded** to Intune **programmatically**.

I've check [Azure Intune REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/intune/) but can't find this feature.

I know that SCCM can integrate Intune, so could I use SCCM PowerShell to achieve the Intune App deployment automation?

Or some other way is possible?

Much appreciated.

Comment: There're some guides in docs about how to create Android/IOS apps through Graph API (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_apps_androidlobapp_create) . Also this thread should have some helps for you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787865/400-bad-request-when-creating-app-in-intune-using-microsoft-graph-api

Comment: And of course it is also possible if you are using Intune Hybrid. There's no much differences from creating normal Win32 apps in ConfigMgr through Powershell scripts. What you need to do is: 1.Create the Application; 2.Create the Deployment Type; 3.Distribute the Content to Could DP; 4. Deploy the Apps.